# Rebind Control+LeftClick in Resharper

Tags: resharper

I want Control+LeftClick in Resharper to be bound to 'Goto Implementation' instead of 'Goto Declaration'. This is because I work with lots of interfaces, and most of the time I want to visit the implementation not the interface declaration. Is there any way of doing this?

I know about `ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Search & Navigation` to enable or disable the `Go to declaration on <Control + Left click>`. But I want to *rebind* the keyboard gesture, not disable it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to rebind the ctrl-click behaviour, unfortunately. However, the behaviour has been extended in 8.1 ([just hit beta](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/11/beta-updates-to-resharper-8-and-net-tools/)). It's now like this:

- Ctrl+click: Go to declaration
- Ctrl+alt+click: Go to implementation
- Ctrl+shift+click: Peek definition (in VS2013)

Here's the issue ticket: [RSRP-203864](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-203864)