# Resharper - is it possible to go to method's implementation on CTRL-click instead of going to declaration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

if I do CTRL-click on method's name in VS2012 with Resharper 8, I'm redirected to the method's "declaration" - and that's quite inconvenient if I have lots of interfaces in my project.

If it possible to configure resharper to go right to the IMPLEMENTATIONS of the method (and if there is more than one - display a context menu which I need to select the desired method from)? I can achieve this if I do right-click -> "Go to Implementation" but I really prefer to have this on ctrl-click.

Comment: I just "Go to definition" then press Alt + End on the interface. It takes you to its implementation. Extra key press.. but not too bad.

Comment: See my answer to the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179998/rebind-controlleftclick-in-resharper/20195658#20195658

Comment: Alt + F12 = Peek Definition, then
ALT + End = Peek Implementation

Answer (score 90, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+Click = Go to declaration

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+Click = Go to implementation

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+Click = Peek to declaration (Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: Is there an alternative to that mouse click?

Comment: ctrl+alt+click does goto implementation, but it opens it in a new pane. WHYYYYY?? Can I turn off that new pane and just have a normal tab?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can re-assign the CTRL+LeftClick Option.  [Per their documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Declaration.html).

> By default, **Go To Declaration** is available by **Ctrl + left-click**. To
>   *change* the default behavior, use controls on the **Search & Navigation**
>   page of the **Options** dialog box. For more information, see ReSharper
>   Options: Environment: Search & Navigation

Since it says "change", I went and checked the **Search & Navigation** section mentioned above to verify if this behavior can indeed be changed. But the change is simply a `Checkbox` that says.

```
Go To Declaration on <Control + Left Click> in editor.
```

I unchecked this option and saved it, and now, I get nothing if I `CTRL+Left Click` a method name. So I think you can only disable or enable this option, not re-assign the keys.

Answer (score 5):

Keyboard only options:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> OR <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> = Go to implementation

<kbd>F12</kbd> = Go to declaration

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>  = Peek declaration

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 solutions for it:

1. CTRL + ALT + Left Click - default behaviour
2. VS: Tools => Option => Environment => keyboard => Search "ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoImplementation" and then assign the key you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. install MiddleClickDefinition extention by norachuga
2. restart VS
3. ctrl+middleclick and enjoy!

worked in my VS2022